# Storing an object in array

Tags: java, class, object

My code is supposed to read a sequence until the empty line. I am stuck at storing the object in array at `numItem` and then increase `numItem`.

```
public static int readInput(Scanner myScanner, String[] input) {
    boolean streamEnded = false;
    int numItem = 0;
    while (!streamEnded && myScanner.hasNext()) {
        String name = myScanner.nextLine();
        String id = myScanner.nextLine();
        if (name.length() == 0 && id.length() == 0) {
            streamEnded = true;
        } else {
            input[numItem] = name;
            input[numItem] = id;
            numItem++;
        }

        Person personTest = new Person(name, id);
        persons[numItem]

    }
    return numItem;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Put the `numItem` increment outside of the `if/else` statement. It should go at the end of your while loop after `persons[numItem]`.
2. Not sure what this: `persons[numItem]` is supposed to do. If you mean to store the personTest object at that index it should be `persons[numItem] = personTest;`.
3. Unless you know you are only going to have 10 people created in your array, I would use an `ArrayList`, that way you could add as many `Person` objects as you need.

I didn't go through it line by line, those are just my general observations. I'm pretty sure your code won't compile as it is, especially with this: `persons[numItem]`. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    while (myScanner.hasNext()) {
        String inp = myScanner.nextLine();

        if (inp.length() <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        String[] parts = inp.split(" ");
        persons.add(new Person(parts[0], parts[1]));
    }

    while (myScanner.hasNext()) {
        String inp = myScanner.nextLine();

        if (inp.length() <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        String[] parts = inp.split(" ");
        Person person = findPerson(persons, parts[0]);
        person.changeBalance(Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
        System.out.println(person);
    }

}

private static Person findPerson(List<Person> persons, String id) {
    for (Person person : persons) {
        if (person.getId().equals(id)) {
            return person;
        }
    }
    return new Person("", "");
}
```

Here I have used a `ArrayList` instead of array to make things easier. I have printed the person every time the balance changes. But, you can move it outside of the loop to match your output.